# Derivative of an integral (Functional Derivative)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How can I get the derivative with respect to $x_t$:

$(\int_0^1 x_t^\alpha dt )^\frac{1}{\alpha}$

Comment: I don't think that makes much sense... An index is merely a way to ennumerate things, not a variable. Do you have the definition of that integral?

Comment: This is based on economics. The integral is an aggregate of consumption $x_i$ for individual i. Given the above function to power of  $\alpha$. To maximize by a choice of $x_i$ the derivative is required. @DonAntonio Thank you

Comment: Fine, thanks. But then you should have, perhaps, written that in the question and/or tag the question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the functional derivative $$\frac{\delta}{\delta x_t}\left(\int_0^1 x_{t^\prime}^{\alpha} dt^\prime\right)^{1/\alpha}=\frac{1}{\alpha}\left(\int_0^1 x_{t^\prime}^{\alpha} dt^\prime\right)^{1/\alpha-1}\frac{\delta}{\delta x_t}\int_0^1 x_{t^\prime}^{\alpha} dt^\prime\\=x_t^{\alpha-1}\left(\int_0^1 x_{t^\prime}^{\alpha} dt^\prime\right)^{1/\alpha-1}\frac{\delta}{\delta x_t^{\alpha}}\int_0^1 x_{t^\prime}^{\alpha} dt^\prime.$$Write $y_t:=x_t^\alpha$ so $$\frac{\delta y_{t^\prime}}{\delta y_t}=\delta(t-t^\prime),\,\frac{\delta}{\delta y_t}\int_0^1 y_{t^\prime}dt^\prime=\int_0^1\delta(t-t^\prime)dt^\prime=1.$$Hence$$\frac{\delta}{\delta x_t}\left(\int_0^1 x_{t^\prime}^{\alpha} dt^\prime\right)^{1/\alpha}=x_t^{\alpha-1}\left(\int_0^1 x_{t^\prime}^{\alpha} dt^\prime\right)^{1/\alpha-1}.$$

Comment: Thank you! I was not familiar with functional derivative. What if we have two functions together. How can I get the derivative with respect to $x_t$ in : 
$(\int_0^1  z_t x_t dt )$

Comment: @Faye It'd be $\int_0^1 z_{t^\prime}\delta(t-t^\prime)dt^\prime=z_t$, assuming $z$ is $x$-independent. (BTW, always use a dummy integration variable differing from the argument of the function with respect to which you're taking a functional derivative.) We get there from first principles; $\delta x_{t^\prime}/\delta x_t=\delta (t-t^\prime)$, a Dirac delta, is analogous to partial derivatives $\partial q_i/\partial q_j=\delta_{ij}$, a Kronecker delta, for discretely labelled variables.

Comment: Thank you for the reference to the Dirac delta! Appreciated.